# Internal error 500 in ASP.Net after AJAX request

Tags: asp.net

this code working in aspx, but this code in not working in mvc project..
error: POST http://localhost:1208/AWD/Login.asmx/logi 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
var Email = $("#uwd").val();
var pwd = $("#pwd").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/AWD/Login.asmx/logi",
    data: "{'username':'" + Email + "','password':'" + pwd + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var obj = response.d;
        alert(obj);
        if (obj == "01") {
            alert("login ok");
        }
        else {
            alert("login no");
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

[WebMethod]

```
public static string logi(string username,string password)
{
    string result = null;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand ilogin = new SqlCommand("select *from login where email='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "' ", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ilogin);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        result = "ok";
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        result ="no";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: A 500 status code means the problem is with your code in the ASPX file. Also note that you would be better to provide an actual object to the `data` parameter so that jQuery can encode the values for you correctly, instead of hacking together a JSON string.

Comment: Is their incorrect `url`? Please check may be it is `/login` then `/logi"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems its not valid JSON string. try use following:
data: '{"username":"'+ Email + '","password":"' + pwd + '"}'.

Answer (score 0):

first try  Restart your IIS
and pleas post your ASP code to check it i think you post parameter to get page or you don't  use the authentication attributes

and the url you use is  /logi !! is that right 
i think wrong url it is /login